# Creating a file programmatically that has a specific ID

Tags: file-upload, content-database

Is this remotely possible?

I am trying to correct some orphaned entries (specifically webparts) in the content database's AllWebparts table (they have PageUrlIDs but no corresponding entries in the AllDocs table) and am wondering if there is a supported method of creating a file/webpart page so that it has a specific ID.

If I can, then hopefully either the error will go away and the pages stay there forever, or the webparts exist in the maintentance page and I can delete them, then the pages and forget this ever happened.

*Edit* Im going to take a wild guess and say no, since that would open up SharePoint for a whole mess of issues if people could decide on the unique identifiers. But, I am getting pretty desperate for a solution at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you can't force specific ID for an item. Neither list specific integer ID, nor the UniqueId (GUID).

You should be able to remove the orphans using SPContentDatabase.Repair ([source](http://www.justinkobel.com/post/2011/07/25/Repairing-a-Content-Database-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx), [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase.repair%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).

```
$db = Get-SPDatabase "Content_DB_Name";
#note set this to $true if you want it to actually repair the database. $false will just list what it would repair
$db.Repair($false);
$db.Update(); #never hurts
```

Comment: Ill give that a shot right now. If it works I am going to kick myself in the ass.

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work. And after checking the msdn entry, it only looks for lists, spsite and spweb objects.

Comment: Too bad it didn't help :( MSDN article says it should also affect documents: "...to delete corrupted site collections, Web sites, lists, and documents..."

Comment: While it will, I need it to remove orphaned webparts.